# Javascript - Add and remove class when we tap on div

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
  if($(window).width() < 768){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.nb-team-grid').on('click', function(e){
          $('.nb-team-info').toggleClass('test');
        });
    });
}
```

I'm trying to add styles when we tap on a div. I tried but it's not working properly. And I have attached my code above for more clarification. Also I'm attaching my test link, please open that so then you can see the interacition which I want.

http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/test-coder/test.html

Comment: In what file is your script present? - because I see a lot of file not being loaded on your website

Comment: like `http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/test-coder/scripts/script.js` - `404 Not Found`

Comment: and basically all of your other .js files has the same issue

Comment: there isn't even a folder called `scripts` in your projects folder - http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/test-coder/

Comment: Hey Stender, I just added that I used separately. And when we click on other div the previous selected div shoud remove the style. And also when click on the same div again the also have to remove it's self.

Comment: What I meant now that interaction is working non css. But it should work on clikc in mobile, for that I need your help.

Comment: And I have added your script to my test work. This is the link for that http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/test-coder/test.html. Can you check this please? Here when I click on one div the style effecting all the div at a time.

Comment: Ahh - What you want, is to only toggle the tapped div with a class - and not the rest? right now you are adding `test` to all of the divs on click.?

Comment: `$(this).toggleClass('test');` should do the trick then.

Comment: something like `jQuery('.nb-team-info-grid').on('click', function(){jQuery('.nb-team-info').removeClass('test'); jQuery(this).find('.nb-team-info').toggleClass('test')});`

Comment: feel free to use `$` instead of `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Move the $(document).ready outside of the if statement:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    if($(window).width() < 768){
        $('.nb-team-grid').on('click', function(e){
            $('.nb-team-info').toggleClass('test');
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `$(window).width() <= 768` instead of `$(window).width() < 768` to make code workable in Ipad and less that that. because Ipad has `min-width:768px`. hope this will be useful for you.

```
if($(window).width() <= 768){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.nb-team-grid').on('click', function(e){
          $('.nb-team-info').toggleClass('test');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey Gaurav Rana, I have updated the script using the script above. This is the link for that dev.netbramha.in/projects/test-coder/test.html. Can you check this please? Here when I click on one div the style effecting all the div at a time.

Comment: Replace this code in the above code.
$('.nb-team-grid').on('click', function(e){
    $('.nb-team-grid .nb-team-info').removeClass('test');
          $(this).find('.nb-team-info').toggleClass('test');
        });

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your javascript is checking if the width is 768 on startup. If it is not, the if statement will be completely ignored and never run again. So you need to check the screen width on click instead of on startup.

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nb-team-grid').on('click', function(e){
      if($(window).width() < 768){
         $('.nb-team-info').toggleClass('test');
      }
  });
});
```

Also, if you want to run certain functions when the screen is resized, I would recommend using jQuery's resize event like this:

```
$(window).on('resize', () =>{
   if($(window).width < 800){  //You can monitor for your own width, I just chose 800.
      // functions to run
   }
});
```